# QMainWindow not responding when OpenCV process is running

Tags: opencv, qtgui

I'm using a custom OpenCV VideoProcessor-Class in my QtGui-Application. My MainWindow has 2 ViewerWidgets for displaying the Input and the Output frames produced by the VideoProcessor Object. The VideoProcessor-Object takes pointers on those ViewerWidgets for displaying the processed frames on these Widgets.

When I start the Application everything in the GUI-Window responds to user input. But when I start the Processing it stops responding. I can't even close the Window or select something from the Application Menu. The processing shows the correct output and keeps running but the Window doesn't respond any more.

This is the MainWindow's Slot that starts the processing:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionStart_Capture_triggered()
{
    // Create instance
    p = new VideoProcessor();
          // Open video file
          p->setInput(0);
          // Declare a window to display the video
          p->displayInput("Current Frame");
          p->displayOutput("Output Frame");
          // Play the video at the original frame rate
          p->setDelay(1000./p->getFrameRate());
          // Set the frame processor callback function
          p->setFrameProcessor(canny);
          // Start the process
          p->run(cvWidgetIn, cvWidgetOut);
}
```

And this is the VideoProcessor. The File is from OpenCV Cookbook and I changed it to take pointers to my ViewerWidgets in the run() Function at the end of the code below.

```
#if !defined VPROCESSOR
#define VPROCESSOR

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "cvwidget.h"

// The frame processor interface
class FrameProcessor {

  public:
    // processing method
    virtual void process(cv:: Mat &input, cv:: Mat &output)= 0;
};

class VideoProcessor {

  private:

      // the OpenCV video capture object
      cv::VideoCapture capture;
      // the callback function to be called 
      // for the processing of each frame
      void (*process)(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&);
      // the pointer to the class implementing 
      // the FrameProcessor interface
      FrameProcessor *frameProcessor;
      // a bool to determine if the 
      // process callback will be called
      bool callIt;
      // Input display window name
      std::string windowNameInput;
      // Output display window name
      std::string windowNameOutput;
      // delay between each frame processing
      int delay;
      // number of processed frames 
      long fnumber;
      // stop at this frame number
      long frameToStop;
      // to stop the processing
      bool stop;

      // vector of image filename to be used as input
      std::vector<std::string> images; 
      // image vector iterator
      std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator itImg;

      // the OpenCV video writer object
      cv::VideoWriter writer;
      // output filename
      std::string outputFile;

      // current index for output images
      int currentIndex;
      // number of digits in output image filename
      int digits;
      // extension of output images
      std::string extension;

      // to get the next frame 
      // could be: video file; camera; vector of images
      bool readNextFrame(cv::Mat& frame) {

          if (images.size()==0)
              return capture.read(frame);
          else {

              if (itImg != images.end()) {

                  frame= cv::imread(*itImg);
                  itImg++;
                  return frame.data != 0;
              }
          }
      }

      // to write the output frame 
      // could be: video file or images
      void writeNextFrame(cv::Mat& frame) {

          if (extension.length()) { // then we write images

              std::stringstream ss;
              ss << outputFile << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(digits) << currentIndex++ << extension;
              cv::imwrite(ss.str(),frame);

          } else { // then write video file

              writer.write(frame);
          }
      }

  public:

      // Constructor setting the default values
      VideoProcessor() : callIt(false), delay(-1), 
          fnumber(0), stop(false), digits(0), frameToStop(-1), 
          process(0), frameProcessor(0) {}

      // set the name of the video file
      bool setInput(std::string filename) {

        fnumber= 0;
        // In case a resource was already 
        // associated with the VideoCapture instance
        capture.release();
        images.clear();

        // Open the video file
        return capture.open(filename);
      }

      // set the camera ID
      bool setInput(int id) {

        fnumber= 0;
        // In case a resource was already 
        // associated with the VideoCapture instance
        capture.release();
        images.clear();

        // Open the video file
        return capture.open(id);
      }

      // set the vector of input images
      bool setInput(const std::vector<std::string>& imgs) {

        fnumber= 0;
        // In case a resource was already 
        // associated with the VideoCapture instance
        capture.release();

        // the input will be this vector of images
        images= imgs;
        itImg= images.begin();

        return true;
      }

      // set the output video file
      // by default the same parameters than input video will be used
      bool setOutput(const std::string &filename, int codec=0, double framerate=0.0, bool isColor=true) {

          outputFile= filename;
          extension.clear();

          if (framerate==0.0) 
              framerate= getFrameRate(); // same as input

          char c[4];
          // use same codec as input
          if (codec==0) { 
              codec= getCodec(c);
          }

          // Open output video
          return writer.open(outputFile, // filename
              codec, // codec to be used 
              framerate,      // frame rate of the video
              getFrameSize(), // frame size
              isColor);       // color video?
      }

      // set the output as a series of image files
      // extension must be ".jpg", ".bmp" ...
      bool setOutput(const std::string &filename, // filename prefix
          const std::string &ext, // image file extension 
          int numberOfDigits=3,   // number of digits
          int startIndex=0) {     // start index

          // number of digits must be positive
          if (numberOfDigits<0)
              return false;

          // filenames and their common extension
          outputFile= filename;
          extension= ext;

          // number of digits in the file numbering scheme
          digits= numberOfDigits;
          // start numbering at this index
          currentIndex= startIndex;

          return true;
      }

      // set the callback function that will be called for each frame
      void setFrameProcessor(void (*frameProcessingCallback)(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&)) {

          // invalidate frame processor class instance
          frameProcessor= 0;
          // this is the frame processor function that will be called
          process= frameProcessingCallback;
          callProcess();
      }

      // set the instance of the class that implements the FrameProcessor interface
      void setFrameProcessor(FrameProcessor* frameProcessorPtr) {

          // invalidate callback function
          process= 0;
          // this is the frame processor instance that will be called
          frameProcessor= frameProcessorPtr;
          callProcess();
      }

      // stop streaming at this frame number
      void stopAtFrameNo(long frame) {

          frameToStop= frame;
      }

      // process callback to be called
      void callProcess() {

          callIt= true;
      }

      // do not call process callback
      void dontCallProcess() {

          callIt= false;
      }

      // to display the processed frames
      void displayInput(std::string wn) {

          windowNameInput= wn;
          //cv::namedWindow(windowNameInput);
      }

      // to display the processed frames
      void displayOutput(std::string wn) {

          windowNameOutput= wn;
          //cv::namedWindow(windowNameOutput);
      }

      // do not display the processed frames
      void dontDisplay() {

          cv::destroyWindow(windowNameInput);
          cv::destroyWindow(windowNameOutput);
          windowNameInput.clear();
          windowNameOutput.clear();
      }

      // set a delay between each frame
      // 0 means wait at each frame
      // negative means no delay
      void setDelay(int d) {

          delay= d;
      }

      // a count is kept of the processed frames
      long getNumberOfProcessedFrames() {

          return fnumber;
      }

      // return the size of the video frame
      cv::Size getFrameSize() {

        if (images.size()==0) {

            // get size of from the capture device
            int w= static_cast<int>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
            int h= static_cast<int>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

            return cv::Size(w,h);

        } else { // if input is vector of images

            cv::Mat tmp= cv::imread(images[0]);
            if (!tmp.data) return cv::Size(0,0);
            else return tmp.size();
        }
      }

      // return the frame number of the next frame
      long getFrameNumber() {

        if (images.size()==0) {

            // get info of from the capture device
            long f= static_cast<long>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES));
            return f; 

        } else { // if input is vector of images

            return static_cast<long>(itImg-images.begin());
        }
      }

      // return the position in ms
      double getPositionMS() {

          // undefined for vector of images
          if (images.size()!=0) return 0.0;

          double t= capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);
          return t; 
      }

      // return the frame rate
      double getFrameRate() {

          // undefined for vector of images
          if (images.size()!=0) return 0;

          double r= capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
          return r; 
      }

      // return the number of frames in video
      long getTotalFrameCount() {

          // for vector of images
          if (images.size()!=0) return images.size();

          long t= capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
          return t; 
      }

      // get the codec of input video
      int getCodec(char codec[4]) {

          // undefined for vector of images
          if (images.size()!=0) return -1;

          union {
              int value;
              char code[4]; } returned;

          returned.value= static_cast<int>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC));

          codec[0]= returned.code[0];
          codec[1]= returned.code[1];
          codec[2]= returned.code[2];
          codec[3]= returned.code[3];

          return returned.value;
      }

      // go to this frame number
      bool setFrameNumber(long pos) {

          // for vector of images
          if (images.size()!=0) {

              // move to position in vector
              itImg= images.begin() + pos;
              // is it a valid position?
              if (pos < images.size())
                  return true;
              else
                  return false;

          } else { // if input is a capture device

            return capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
          }
      }

      // go to this position
      bool setPositionMS(double pos) {

          // not defined in vector of images
          if (images.size()!=0) 
              return false;
          else 
              return capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, pos);
      }

      // go to this position expressed in fraction of total film length
      bool setRelativePosition(double pos) {

          // for vector of images
          if (images.size()!=0) {

              // move to position in vector
              long posI= static_cast<long>(pos*images.size()+0.5);
              itImg= images.begin() + posI;
              // is it a valid position?
              if (posI < images.size())
                  return true;
              else
                  return false;

          } else { // if input is a capture device

              return capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, pos);
          }
      }

      // Stop the processing
      void stopIt() {

          stop= true;
      }

      // Is the process stopped?
      bool isStopped() {

          return stop;
      }

      // Is a capture device opened?
      bool isOpened() {

          return capture.isOpened() || !images.empty();
      }

      // to grab (and process) the frames of the sequence
      void run(CVWidget *inputWidget, CVWidget *outputWidget) {

          // current frame
          cv::Mat frame;
          // output frame
          cv::Mat output;

          // if no capture device has been set
          if (!isOpened())
              return;

          stop= false;

          while (!isStopped()) {

              // read next frame if any
              if (!readNextFrame(frame))
                  break;

              // display input frame
              if (windowNameInput.length()!=0) 
                 // cv::imshow(windowNameInput,frame);
              inputWidget->sendImage(&frame);


              // calling the process function or method
              if (callIt) {

                // process the frame
                if (process)
                    process(frame, output);
                else if (frameProcessor) 
                    frameProcessor->process(frame,output);
                // increment frame number
                fnumber++;

              } else {

                output= frame;
              }

              // write output sequence
              if (outputFile.length()!=0)
                  writeNextFrame(output);

              // display output frame
              if (windowNameOutput.length()!=0) 
                  //cv::imshow(windowNameOutput,output);
                  outputWidget->sendImage(&output);

              // introduce a delay
              if (delay>=0 && cv::waitKey(delay)>=0)
                stopIt();

              // check if we should stop
              if (frameToStop>=0 && getFrameNumber()==frameToStop)
                  stopIt();
          }
      }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Thank's for the hint. I didn't even know that I can accept answers. Unfortunately I have no clue how to do so. I searched around in my previous conversations and my profile but i didn't find the option to accept anything.

Comment: Under the summary tab of your profile, you will see a header saying, "5 Questions". If you click on each of them, you will see the answers people gave you. Find the one that helped the most and click the outline of the check mark to accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I couldn't find out what the specific reason for my problem has been, I finally found a solution that works for me:

As you suggested I got rid of this VideoProcessor-Utility class and implemented the Processing-Loop for processing frame-Sequences inside the MainWindow by using QTimer for delaying between each frame.

Instead of the VideoProcessor-Class I made "ProcessorWidget". This GUI-Widget provides all the Input Controls for parameterizing each Processor-Function that I have implemented so far.

All the OpenCV code is now in the ProcessorWidget class and it has a public slot cv::Mat process(cv::Mat input) which just takes the Input Frame and then it parses all the User-Input-Parameters from the GUI and handles the choice of the right processor and parameters internally.

The MainWindow now constructs the ViewerWidgets and the ProcessorWidget and owns the Control and Timing.

Processing and Displaying a frame is now just:

```
cvWidgetOut->sendImage(&processor->processFrame(input));
```

And if I want to add more OpenCV Features I don't have to change my MainWindow or GUI. It's all done in the ProcessorWidget-Class.

Answer (score 0):

openCV's highgui window handles it's own event loop - you can't (easily) mix it with QMainWindows event loop.

The easy way is to grab the image in openCV and display in Qt using Qimage and QPainter - the 24bit RGB888 format of QImage is compatible with opencv's CV_8UC3

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I can't see how I'm mixing EventLoops. I don't even use the HighGUI in my code. After removing the highgui-Inclusion from the Videoprocessor-Header it is still working and behaving the same way as I described before.

What I did is replace the functionality of CVNamedWindow with a customized QGLWidget that can take and display cv::Mat frames as Texture-Maps on a GL-Plane.

Comment: EDIT: If I made the MainWindow's ViewerWidgets public members and created the Videoprocessor-Object from the main.cpp, then construct the MainWindow and let the VideoProcessor-Object access the public ViewerWidgets for displaying purposes, would this solve my problem?

Afaik a QMainWindow will always run in it's own Thread and if I don't create the VideoProcessor from within this MainWindow, do you think this could kind of workaround my problem?